# VBA in Excel and Manually Calculating Net Present Value

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub npv()

Dim val As Long
Dim dr As Long
Dim inv As Long
Dim answer As Long
Dim i As Long

dr = Cells(1, 5).Value 'Cells(Row, Column)
inv = Cells(2, 5).Value
val = Cells(1, 1).Value
i = 0

ReDim cashFlow(1 To val) As Long

Do While i < val
    i = i + 1
    cashFlow(i) = Cells((i + 1), 1)
Loop

i = 0
    
Do While i < val
    i = i + 1
    answer = answer + cashFlow(i) / ((1 + dr) ^ i)
Loop

answer = answer - inv

Cells(4, 5).Value = answer

End Sub
```

Hello, I am trying to figure out why this won't output a proper NPV. With the initial investment of 500, a discount rate of .17, and cash flows 50, 150, 175, 225, it outputs an answer of 100.00. It should be -118.35. I am aware excel has formulas for this, but need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace

```
Dim dr As Long
```

by

```
dim dr as Double
```

Otherwise your discount rate of 0.17 is transformed to a `long` and therefore to `0`.

Comment: Thank you, it works immaculately now. Just out of curiosity, would 'Variant' have worked as well?

Comment: Yes, `Variant` and `Single` work as well.
Just search for VBA data types (e.g. https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/data-types-variables-constants/)